# My Ant scripts stopped to work in the last few days. Could it be related to TLS 1.0 disablement?

Tags: api, deployment, ant, tls

My scripts have been working for years. I made no changes. Token and pass are fine. Last known successful run was about 15 days ago - around 2018-04-10.

Today I got

```
Failed to login: Failed to send request to https://www.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/29.0
```

I never changed anything since years. So never gave TLS 1.0 disablement a thought.

Could it be related?

What should I change?

Answer (score 1):

It had nothing to do with TLS 1.0

The solution on this was very strange and in the file build.properties

I can't say why, but we had here sf.server=https://www.salesforce.com - this does not work since today, but has worked for years.

It is not like stated in the docs:

```
sf.serverurl    

The salesforce server URL. Use https://login.salesforce.com to connect to a production or Developer Edition org. To connect to a sandbox instance, change this to https://test.salesforce.com.
```

Now we had to change it to

```
https://login.salesforce.com/
```

And it worked again.

Obviously Salesforce removed the unsupported redirect from www. to login.